# Printing out multiple hash values from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash-of-hashes

Hi I am trying to push out multiple hash values within a function.  I can only get the first hash to return.  I would like to get all hash values to return so that I can format them after I can pull out the data but so far I am only able to get the value of the first hash.  Thank you in advance for the help here is where I am so far.

```
def list(names)
names.each do|name|
 name.each do |key,value|
   return "#{value}"
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def list(names)
    values = []
    names.each do|name|
        name.each do |key,value|
            values << value
        end
    end
    values
end
```

You need to *keep all* the values, instead of return the first value immediately.

---

Ruby itself has many methods, you can do this very case in one-liner manner.

```
def list(names)
    names.map(&:values).flatten
end
```

Comment: Thanks I love the one liner.